# Is it possible to use jqMath in Windows and Iphone mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, jqmath

I am developing a website which will have some math equations and hence, to render them I am planning to use jqMath. Now, before delving into coding I would like to plan in advance, so that it doesn't turn into a nightmare at the end, and want to know whether jqMath can be used (works) on Mobile apps.

I know Android has WebView and hence jqMath has good performance there.

But I am completely alien to Windows and IOS apps .So I want to know whether jqMath works on those platforms also?

Answer (score 0):

By simply browsing to a jqMath website on the phone I could see that it works perfectly fine.

[image]

close up

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that jqMath is supported on majority of mobile browsers, but I Wanted to know that when I will make a Windows app, then is there something like WebView in Android, so that I can include jqMath library and render the formula??? 

PS: On broswer it works, but I will  not be making a browser, but an app, and hence a mechanism to run that jqMath javascript library

Comment: @InsaneCoder When you use a web control in your application, or when your application is an html app, you're using the built-in browser.  So if it works in the browser, it works in the app.